# innermargin in math environment doesn't work

Tags: math-mode, mdframed

I'm having trouble to make the `innermargin(left and right)` commands work.The equations probably don't let it work. However, it nicely work with simple text(uncomment out in the code to see that).So, my question is how can i also use that command in mathmode.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem,physics,xcolor}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\newcommand{\tani}{\mathrm{tan^{-1}}}
\newcommand{\nonitalic}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
%the command in upper line can be replaced by the following command
%\newcommand{\nit}{\mathrm{d}x}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{leftmargin=.9cm}
\newcommand{\s}{\hspace{2pt}=\hspace{2pt}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Basic Integrals}
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{
    linecolor=red,
    linewidth=5,
    innerlinecolor=white,
    innerlinewidth=4,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    innerrightmargin=.5cm,
    innerleftmargin=.1cm,
    rightmargin=4cm,
    leftmargin=.1cm,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!50!white,
    roundcorner=20pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame]
\begin{enumerate}
\item 
    $\begin{aligned}
    \int \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}  \nonitalic{d}x  
    %\nit 
    \s \frac{1}{a} \tani(\frac{x}{a}) + \text{C}
    \end{aligned}$
\item
    $\begin{aligned}
    \int \frac{1}{x^2-a^2} \nonitalic{d}x \s \frac{1}{2a} \log \abs{\frac{x-a}{x+a}}  + 
    \text{C}
    \end{aligned}$
\item
    $\begin{aligned}
    \int \frac{1}{a^2-x^2} \nonitalic{d}x \s \frac{1}{2a} \log \abs{\frac{a+x}{a-x}}  + 
    \text{C}
    \end{aligned}$
\end{enumerate}
\end{mdframed}
\iffalse
\mdfdefinestyle{MyFrame}{
    linecolor=red,
    linewidth=5,
    innerlinecolor=white,
    innerlinewidth=4,
    topline=false,
    bottomline=false,
    innerrightmargin=1cm,
    innerleftmargin=1cm,
    skipabove=.8cm,
    rightmargin=.4cm,
    leftmargin=.1cm,
    backgroundcolor=yellow!50!white,
    roundcorner=20pt}
\begin{mdframed}[style=MyFrame,align=left]
\lipsum
\end{mdframed}
\fi
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: an image of the code implemented]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I'm unable too understand your question. What exactly do you expect? The box `MyFrame` is defined two times, but not with the same specifications. And what's the purpose of `\iffalse` here?  If for comparison, it's useless (you can redefine the box).

Comment: Off topic: don't use `aligned` if you have nothing to align. If you want large equations, use `$\displaystyle...$`.

Comment: @jlab I meant that the command innerrightmargin or, innerleftmargin doesn't work for the contents in the first mdframed environment, but nicely works in case of simple text which is shown in the later part . you can see that if you remove \iffalse...\fi.

Comment: There is an `enumerate` environment in the first `MyFrame`. It adds its own margins. Since you load the `enumitem` package, does the option `left=0pt` added to `enumerate` (with `\begin{enumerate}[left=0pt]`) gives the expected output ?